# Coming SHA-256 : Do I need to update my IPN listener that does not use a secure URL?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, sha256

I currently use only payment buttons, and an IPN php script I got from https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples that is dated Nov 10, 2014.

My script simply posts back to www.paypal.com without encryption.

Is encryption becoming mandatory ?

Answer (score 3):

Your IPN listener will be responsible to recieve PayPal call-backs and POST them to PayPal for verification. On that point, connection between your server to PayPal endpoint will need encryption with SHA-2.

So literally yes, you would need to check your server key store  / trust store and make sure it includes SHA-2 compatible certs.

You may refer to this [PayPal microsite](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1766&expand=true&locale=en_US) for detailed instructions, these information are open to merchants seeing any impact

Answer (score 1):

You have to verify that your Server supports SHA-2 (SHA-256). Use of SSL with SHA-2 would be manditory.

Since Chrome is deprecating support for SHA-1 by the end of 2015, all PayPal support for SHA-1 will be deprecated by the end of 2016.

You can test your server compatibility here [shaaa..](https://shaaaaaaaaaaaaa.com)

Answer (score 0):

PayPal sandbox environment is supporting SHA2(SHA-256) only. You may make test in below link (need to login with your Live credential) to check if your server could deal with the upgrade now.

https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/

If the test passes, that means your server is able to deal with SHA-2 and you do not need to upgrade the certificate any more. If it fails, please contact your server provider to help you upgrade the SSL certificate.